# how to install linux on windows xp operting system?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, operating-systems

I have a pc with Windows XP installed on it. And I made one partition free of 100 GB for installing Linux(Ubuntu) on it. I am newbie to linux. I searched Google and found some thirdware bootloaders, vmware or virtualbox kind of crap.

I want to dual boot my system. So please mates. Help me in installing

Comment: Did you even bother to read any of the HowTos at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop? E.g. [How to run Ubuntu from a DVD or USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) or [Installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with the Windows installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows)? If you had read our [about](http://superuser.com/about) section you might have noticed that a question requires to show some effort on your own, and be restricted to _one_ clearly and concisely answerable question.

Comment: i am newbie here.. please stop negative voting mates.. i wont reapeat this..

Comment: don't worry too much about these, they usually shouldn't go below -5, just try to ask a more precise question next time (without calling virtual machines crap); and if you include some information what you have already tried (maybe enough to [provide an answer yourself](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)) you may get upvotes instead. Just note that there are more specific [StackExchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/) for [unix/linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) and [ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make [LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) or [LiveUSB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), boot your system from it, not hard drive, and you will have shortcut on the desktop to a script to install it. 
 
Make sure you use option "Install along side my current OS", or chose the partition you made.
As far as commands, start with [basic commands](http://www.my-guides.net/en/guides/linux/basic-linux-commands) and then move on to [advanced](http://ss64.com/bash/).

Regards,
Mirko